# The getter 'secondaryContainer' isn't defined for the class 'ColorScheme'

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion

When I import `Syncfusion` library to my project, these Errors showed me up.

> My Flutter version is `2.4.0-4.0.pre`,

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_gauges-19.4.53/lib/src/radial_gauge/pointers/marker_pointer_renderer.dart:631:34: Error: The getter 'secondaryContainer' isn't defined for the class 'ColorScheme'.
 - 'ColorScheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/color_scheme.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/color_scheme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'secondaryContainer'.
          _themeData.colorScheme.secondaryContainer.withOpacity(0.8)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_gauges-19.4.53/lib/src/radial_gauge/pointers/marker_pointer_renderer.dart:642:36: Error: The getter 'secondaryContainer' isn't defined for the class 'ColorScheme'.
 - 'ColorScheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/color_scheme.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/color_scheme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'secondaryContainer'.
            _themeData.colorScheme.secondaryContainer.withOpacity(0.12)
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_gauges-19.4.53/lib/src/radial_gauge/pointers/range_pointer_renderer.dart:567:34: Error: The getter 'secondaryContainer' isn't defined for the class 'ColorScheme'.
 - 'ColorScheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/color_scheme.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/color_scheme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'secondaryContainer'.
          _themeData.colorScheme.secondaryContainer.withOpacity(0.8)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Try with upgrading flutter version `flutter upgrade`

Answer (score 2):

The properties `primaryVariant` and `secondaryVariant` were replaced with `primaryContainer` and `secondaryContainer` in Flutter v2.6.0-0.0.pre, so to use this version of the plugin you first need to update your Flutter version.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that you are using the flutter stable SDK version 2.4.0-4.0-pre. Update your SDK to the [latest version](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases)(>2.10.0) to solve this issue. If you wish to use the SDK version 2.4.0-4.0-pre only, use the [Flutter Gauge - 19.4.48](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_gauges/versions/19.4.48) version.